# How can I decode the DigitalProductId registry key in java?

Tags: java, windows, registry

I'm trying to grab the product key/id from the following registry key:

```
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion
Key: DigitalProductId
```

However, it is encoded in a way that has not yet been decoded in java. I can retrieve the byte array using JNA, but I cannot decode it.

Here is the C# implementation of the decoder:

```cs
string key = String.Empty;
const int keyOffset = 52;
byte keyBytes = (byte)((digitalProductId[66] / 6) & 1);
digitalProductId[66] = (byte)((digitalProductId[66] & 0xf7) | (keyBytes & 2) * 4);

const string digits = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789";
var last = 0;

for (var i = 24; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var current = 0;
    for (var i2 = 14; i2 >= 0; i2--)
    {
        current *= 256;
        current = digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset] + current;
        digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset] = (byte)(current / 24);
        current %= 24;
        last = current;
    }
    key = digits[current] + key;
}

string keypart1 = key.Substring(1, last);
string keypart2 = key.Substring(last + 1, key.Length - (last + 1));
key = keypart1 + "N" + keypart2;

for (var i3 = 5; i3 < key.Length; i3 += 6)
{
    key = key.Insert(i3, "-");
}
systemInformation.ProductKey = key;
return systemInformation;
```

When I try to port it to Java using the following implementation (FXStringUtil is a class that I made that has an insert function):

```java
String key = "";
int keyOffset = 52;
byte keyBytes = (byte) ((digitalProductId[66] / 6) & 1);
digitalProductId[66] = (byte) ((digitalProductId[66] & 0xf7) | (keyBytes & 2) * 4);

String digits = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789";
int last = 0;

for (int i = 24; i >= 0; i--) {
    int current = 0;
    for (int i2 = 14; i2 >= 0; i2--) {
        current *= 256;
        current = digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset] + current;
        digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset] = (byte) (current / 24);
        current %= 24;
        last = current;
    }
    key = digits.charAt(current) + key;
}

String keypart1 = key.substring(1, last);
String keypart2 = key.substring(last + 1, key.length() - (last + 1));
key = keypart1 + "N" + keypart2;

for (int i3 = 5; i3 < key.length(); i3 += 6) {
    key = FXStringUtil.insertString(key,"-", i3);
}

return key;
```

I get an error on the line containing:

```java
key = digits.charAt(current) + key;
```

of which is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -15
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:712)
    at lol.foxxy.idfkwasbored.util.KeyUtil.DecodeProductKeyWin8AndUp(KeyUtil.java:60)
    at lol.foxxy.idfkwasbored.util.KeyUtil.getProductKey(KeyUtil.java:31)
    at lol.foxxy.idfkwasbored.Main.main(Main.java:123)
```

This error doesn't occur in the C# implementation, so I was wondering why the error occurred. I pinned it down to this line (of which I believe is causing the issue):

```java
current = digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset] + current;
```

However, I don't know exactly what part of this may be causing the issue.

Comment: [Code samples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. This is a well-written question, otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main differences between C# and Java that cause your Java code not to work.

The first is that in C# a `byte` is unsigned whereas in Java a `byte` is signed.

This indeed causes problems in the line you point to in your question:

```java
current = digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset] + current;
```

In Java, `digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset]`, and hence also `digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset] + current`, might be negative.  These negative numbers will then cause the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`s you are getting.

The fix to your Java code is to ensure that `digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset]` in the above line gets converted to an `int` in the range 0 to 255.  The easiest way to do this is to do a bitwise AND with `0xFF`:

```java
current = (digitalProductId[i2 + keyOffset] & 0xFF) + current;
```

The other difference is that in Java, the second parameter to [`String.substring(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) is the end index  (more accurately `String.substring(startIndex, endIndex)` returns the substring from index `startIndex` to index `endIndex - 1`).  However, in C#, the second parameter to [`String.Substring(Int32,Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is the length of the substring.

The two lines that extract the parts of the key should therefore be as follows:

```java
String keypart1 = key.substring(1, last + 1);  // not .substring(1, last)
String keypart2 = key.substring(last + 1);
```

Note that for the second line, I've used the one-argument overload of `String.substring` that takes only the start index and returns the string from there to the end of the string.  You can in fact make the same modification to your C# code:

```cs
string keypart2 = key.Substring(last + 1);
```

I don't have any code to get hold of a product key, so instead I made up some random bytes and ran your C# and modified Java code on this made-up data, and both programs returned the same output.